# How to get date range for current week?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-range

Hello I would like to ask, how can i do it in Javascript or in Javascript library Moment.js http://momentjs.com/docs/ (I prefer this library) following:

```
Today is date (for example): 18-09-2014
```

I need from given date get range for actual week (from monday to sunday), it means that for 
given date i should to get result:

```
start: 15-09-2014
end: 21-09-2014
```

Is it possible and how can i do it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What did you try? If you solve it yourself, you win.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Take given date's day, create a new date, subtract the days, there is your start. Add 7 days to get the end.

Comment: When not using momentjs:
https://codepen.io/Venugopal46/pen/WrxdLY

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess:

```
moment().day(1); // Monday
moment().day(7); // Sunday
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
Date.prototype.getWeek = function(start)
{
        // the starting point
    start = start || 0;
    var today = new Date(this.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = today.getDay() - start;
    var date = today.getDate() - day;

        //  Start/End Dates
    var StartDate = new Date(today.setDate(date));
    var EndDate = new Date(today.setDate(date + 6));
    return [StartDate, EndDate];
}

// test code
var Dates = new Date().getWeek();
alert(Dates[0].toLocaleDateString() + ' to '+ Dates[1].toLocaleDateString())
</script>
```

Comment: This code produces incorrect EndDate if end date should be in other month - [Aug 31 2014, Aug 06 2014].